# Difference between data

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have the same type of output data from different scenarios at various time steps. I need to find out the difference in values if any .

For example, data colums:

```
Timestep, DataX_derivedfromA, DataX_derivedfromB, DataXderivedfromC, DataXderivedfromD
```

How can I find out if the max diff at each time step.
What are the other statistical methods I could use to show the difference in values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum difference between any two elements will be the difference between the largest and the smallest:

```
data = [1 -1 5 2; -3 -7 3 4];
max_diff = max(data, [], 2) - min(data, [], 2)
max_diff =
6
11
```

You can find the indices of the columns responsible for the min and max values using blkproc (or blockfun from the File Exchange if you do not have the imaging toolkit).

```
fun = @(x) [find(x==min(x)) find(x==max(x))];
idx = blkproc(data, [1 4], fun)

idx =
 2     3
 2     4
```

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand what you are trying to achieve, but hopefully this helps:

```
fromA = [1 2 3 5];
fromB = [1 3 4.5 2];

M = [fromA; fromB];

option1 = max(diff(M')')
```

Or perhaps you are looking for this:

```
option2 = max(M) - min(M)
```